# How do I Listen Over a Socket for Incoming Connections After the Last Connection is Closed?

Tags: c#, sockets, listener

I'm setting up a socket to listen for incoming connections:

```
public Socket Handler;

public void StartListening()
{
    // Establish the locel endpoint for the socket
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try
    {
        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen
        listener.Blocking = false;
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(100);

        // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections
        listener.BeginAccept( new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        invokeStatusUpdate(0, e.Message);
    }            
}

private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Get the socket that handles the client request
    Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
    Handler = handler;

    // Create the state object
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
}
```

As you can see above, once a connection is made, I setup my BeginReceive callback. This works fine.

Eventually I get to a point where I want to close the current connection and then begin listening on my socket again for an incomming connection attempt:

```
public void CloseNode(bool restart)
{
    try
    {
        if (Handler != null)
        {
            Handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            Handler.Close();
            Handler.Dispose();
            Handler = null;
        }

        if (restart)
            StartListening();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        invokeStatusUpdate(0, e.Message);
    }
}
```

My close method takes a boolean to know if it should start listening for more incoming connections.

The problem is that when I go back into my `StartListening` method, I get an exception on the line `listener.Bind(localEndPoint);` saying that **"Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"**.

How do I go about setting up my listening to begin listening again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it out into two methods: `startListening()` and `continueListening()`

Start listening will initialize everything and then call continue listening. Where you're calling start listening at the end now, call continue listening instead.

Or if you want to allow more than one at a time, just put the `BeginAccept` call in a `while(true)` loop. This will accept all incoming connections forever, even if someone else has connected. That's why it's asynchronous after all!

Here's your member variables

```
public Socket Handler;
private socket listener; // added by corsiKa
```

Here's your new start method

```
public void StartListening()
{
    // Establish the locel endpoint for the socket
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket
    listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try
    {
        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen
        listener.Blocking = false;
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(100);

        // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections
        performListen(listener); // changed by corsiKa
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        invokeStatusUpdate(0, e.Message);
    }            
}
```

Here's your perform listen method

```
// added by corsiKa
private void performListen(Socket listener) {
    listener.BeginAccept( new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
}
```

Here's your new close method

```
// variable name changed by corsiKa
public void CloseNode(bool acceptMoreConnections)
{
    try
    {
        if (Handler != null)
        {
            Handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            Handler.Close();
            Handler.Dispose();
            Handler = null;
        }
        // changed by corsiKa
        if (acceptMoreConnections)
            performListen(listener);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        invokeStatusUpdate(0, e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I only want one connection at a time. I'm not sure where I would split up the method to do what you suggest. Should I make that socket global and have the `ContinueListening` method simply call `BeginAccept`?

Comment: You actually could just replace your `if(restart) startListening();` with `if(restart) listener.BeginAccept( new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);` Obviously that will require providing access to the socket.

Comment: Added code. I'm not a c# guy, I'm a Java guy. So some of the syntax may be wrong. But I imagine there's a problem it will be simple enough to fix.

Comment: This works great. Thank you for the help. If you don't mind, could you explain why there are two sockets being implemented here? Between the Listener and handler I get a bit confused on their roles.

Comment: I don't know what your Handler socket does. I completely ignored it.

Comment: @MichaelMankus Socket.Accept() returns a socket for an incoming connection. The listener can then continue listening for incoming connections while you handle whatever needs to happen with the socket you've accepted. So, at the very least, you'd end up with at least two sockets, one that the server uses to listen and one that it uses to respond to an incoming connection. I'm not sure why you hold a global reference - but it appears your design is such that there's only one incoming connection that's handled at a time, so that's probably ok.